Webpack: stop css-loader from replacing svg urls with hashed svgs
I realized that my project at some point stopped showing svgs which I link from my scss files.
I have lines like:
background-image: url('./assets/icons/check-icon.svg');
Webpack, I suspect it's the css-loader as I commented all other css-loaders out, now creates hashed svg files like 71348f532d829722222a.svg directly in my dist folder.
The file itself is no svg but JavaScript, probably for using svgs in other places than css:
export default {
      id: "check-icon",
      viewBox: "0 0 512 512",
      url: __webpack_public_path__ + "/Users/USER/Documents/fe/src/assets/icons/check-icon.svg",
      toString: function () {
        return this.url;
      }
    }

Now of course my css is trying to load this file and it cannot be displayed.
Webpack also creates a copy of the actual folders within my dist:
dist/assets/icons/... so if the url() part of my css was not replace with this hashed svg but still would be pointing to url('./assets/icons/check-icon.svg') everything would work. But how can I achieve that?
Here is part of my webpack config:
{
    test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
    use: [
        'style-loader',
        {
            loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
            options: {
                esModule: false,
            },
        },
        {
            loader: 'css-loader', // <--- probably the culprit
        },
        'postcss-loader',
        {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            options: {
                implementation: require('sass'),
                sourceMap: true,
            },
        },
    ],
}

And here is another part where I test for svgs:
{
    test: /\.svg$/,
    use: [
        {
            loader: 'svg-sprite-loader',
            options: {
                runtimeCompat: true,
            },
        },
    ],
    include: [/assets/],
},

If I comment the latter it won't make any difference though. The file within the css is still linked to the non-working svg with the hash.

You might have to test for svg as well ( I had this in my config: test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+.\d+.\d+)?$/, and use the loader: 'url-loader', . Options depending on your project (include, exclude, name/path etc.).

Can you elaborate on this? I don't really understand. I will add my part where I test for svgs above, maybe that helps to understand the problem.

It's a while ago I used Webpack and I never was an Webpack-expert - so I just took a look at one of my last config files because I remembered that I had issues with svg as well. So I post the test-parts for .svg files here - hoping it can lead you into the right direction. As you can see I have two tests because I had the problem that Webpack saved all .svg files in my images directory and I didn't want that for fonts (of type .svg). So the first test is for handling all .svg but beeing fonts and the second for font-svgs.
exclude font directory on first test
{
    test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+.\d+.\d+)?$/,
    exclude: [
        `${settings.dirs.srcPath}fonts`
    ],
    loader: 'url-loader',
    options: {
        publicPath: settings.cssUrlPath,
        limit: settings.build.images.limit,
        mimetype: 'image/svg+xml',
        name: ifProduction(path.join(settings.build.images.dir, `[name]${settings.build.hash ? '.[hash:8]' : ''}.[ext]`), path.join(settings.build.images.dir, '[name].[ext]'))
    }
},

include only fonts directory on second test
{
    test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+.\d+.\d+)?$/,
    include: [
        `${settings.dirs.srcPath}fonts`
    ],
    loader: 'url-loader',
    options: {
        publicPath: settings.cssUrlPath,
        limit: settings.build.images.limit,
        mimetype: 'image/svg+xml',
        name: ifProduction(path.join(settings.build.fonts.dir, `[name]${settings.build.hash ? '.[hash:8]' : ''}.[ext]`), path.join(settings.build.fonts.dir, '[name].[ext]'))
    }
},

The used variables here are of course project related so you have to adjust that (or remove entirely) according your file-structure. I had a settings.build.images.limit value of 20480. Not sure - I think it was the limit for not writing svg inline as base64 (in css code).
Like said I'm no expert here - hope this can at least be a good starting point to solve your issue.

Thanks for the effort. Indeed I have a similar setup already where I need to handle fonts and images differently. That is no problem. I think if I knew how to disable the replacement of my correctly written scss with the path to the hashed version it would all work... I just can't figure out which element (I guess its the css-loader) is responsible and further how to disabled manipulating my css in that regard...

I believe the url-loader is responsible for linked files like background-images in your SCSS. But if the only problem you have is the unwanted renaming (with hashes in filenames) I assume you have to look at the ' options: { name: ###} ' part. I guess you need to set it like [name].[ext] - plus the path to the destination directory prepending. Or did I get you wrong and Webpack puts the hashes into your css but not to the filenames?

webpack puts the hashes into my css AND also creates corrupt svg files with that hashed name. Also it creates a copy of the svg with its original filename. So I could ignore that there are ~JavaScript SVGs as long as my css would not link to the hashed files...

Well in my case a fix was using /* webpackIgnore: true */
in front of the SVGs I wanted to use in scss.
I have not found an answer which prevents replacement completely, but because I only had a few cases I was a viable solution:
Something like this.
/* webpackIgnore: true */
background: url('./assets/icons/swc_rating_star_icon.svg') repeat-x;

Also described here: https://webpack.js.org/loaders/css-loader/#disable-url-resolving-using-the--webpackignore-true--comment
